# How to connect to database in zendFramework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I can't find where to connect to the database in ZF2, where to create the application.ini to setup required data or in the module->bootstrap method, please help

Comment: Did you succeed with connecting to the database?

Answer (score 6):

As others have pointed out, you can add something like the following to your `config/autoload/global.php` or `config/autoload/local.php`.

```
'db' => array(
    'driver' => 'Pdo',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:dbname=mydb;host=localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'driver_options' => array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
    ),
),
```

Note that it is best practice to add sensitive information (e.g. the password) to the `local.php` file. The reason is that this file should be ignored by version control software and is ignored by Git by default if you are using the Zend Skeleton Application due to a `.gitignore` file.

To use the connection, you can fetch the database adapter from the service manager. For instance, you can do the following in a controller action:

```
public function someAction() {
    $dbAdapter = $this->serviceLocator->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');

    // Do something with the database adapter, e.g.:
    $dbAdapter->query('SELECT username FROM user WHERE id = ?', array(37));
}
```

The [manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/index.html#zend-db) should get you started on how you can use the database adapter to execute queries; you will probably want to make use of `Zend\Db\Sql`, so the above is just an example. Note that you would ideally not access the database (i.e. execute database queries) directly within your controllers, but the above is just an example; it is quite easy to inject the database adapter into a [Data Access Layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_layer) (DAL) or service layer if you are using any of those design patterns.

What happens above is that the `Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory` is invoked. This happens because the class implements the `Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface`, which the service manager checks against (see the [service manager's source code](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php#L867) for more information).

The `Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory` factory [fetches the configuration from the service manager and reads the 'db' key](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/AdapterServiceFactory.php#L25-L26). This configuration (as shown in the first code example) is then passed to the `Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter`'s [constructor](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Adapter.php#L80) which configures the instantiated database adapter.

So, all you have to do is to configure your database connection under the `db` key in a configuration file and fetch it with the `Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter` key from the service manager - then the rest is done for you automatically.

**EDIT:**

Make sure that you have enabled the `AdapterServiceFactory` in your configuration for the above to work. Provided that you are using the ZendSkeletonApplication, add the below within `config/autoload/global.php`.

```
return array(
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 2):

to config ( global.php etc ):

```
'db' => array(
  'driver' => 'Pdo',
  'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=mydb;host=localhost',
  'username'       => 'mydb',
  'password'       => '',
  'driver_options' => array(
      PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
  ),
```

Comment: it will connect automatically? if i add this array to the globals or where do I need to connect?

Answer (score 1):

Go to diectory : you_application_folder/config/autoload/

in global.php

```
<?php
return array(
'db' => array(
  'driver' => 'Pdo',
  'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=mydb;host=localhost',
  'driver_options' => array(
      PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
  ),
);

?>
```

in local.php // save important data here

```
<?php
return array(
'db' => array(
  'username'       => '*****',
  'password'       => '*****',
);

?>
```

Comment: thats good, but where do i need to make the connection itself?