# Zend prevent database connection on concrete action

Tags: database, zend-framework2

Is this possible to prevent database connection while I requests concrete action in Zend Framework 2?

Comment: i want to prevent connect to database in cause of request page by definied request

Comment: I still don't understand it, if a certain action of your controller is not supposed to call the DB, then simply don't? Please provide an actual use-case, this question is just so hard to grasp...

Comment: All images on my website are generated by zend, so I have link to them like that: /photo,23432,w89eo5w4985i234/. In any case I dont need a database connection and my website's going slow on many requests (I have 150+ images/subpage). I don't know how to fix that so I though this is problem with many connections to a database on any image request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sam stated in a comment; if you do not wish to establish a connection to the database, then simply don't. If you do not have any code within your controller action that uses the database, then there won't be a database connection (provided that you are not doing funky stuff in a bootstrap method or similar).

If you are building a database connection in [the standard way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15700626/how-to-connect-to-database-in-zendframework-2/15725279#15725279), then the actual connection will be lazily loaded, meaning that there won't be an actual connection before you try to use it.

In your comment you state that you believe the problem is caused by many database connections. I just want to clarify that there will only be one database connection per request (provided that you make use of the database).

If you have no code that calls a database, then your web server won't actually make a connection to your database. Either way, if you have 150+ images per page, then that would be a bigger concern and is probably the root cause for slow page loads. Perhaps consider pagination or if you do not display the pictures in their full sizes, then avoid scaling them in HTML as you would then be sending lots of unnecessary data from your web server to your visitors. You could resize the pictures in PHP when they are added, for instance. After that, you could even consider using a Content Delivery Network (CDN), but that is a different discussion...